# How to horizontally center the last item of a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is a way to horizontally center the last item in a recycler view.
So...if there is only one item this item will be centered and will not scroll, if there is two or more that can fill the width it will be possible to scroll, but the last item will appears first on center

For example. In the following images, every time a new search category (iPhone, Celulares e Smartphones) are added, the last item is centralized.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you paste what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried nothing yet. I'm looking for some guide or solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it in your adapter. I have never did something like this, but my try would be something like this:

On the method `onBindViewHolder`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        OrderItem item = items.get(position);

        //last item
        if(position == item.size()-1){
               holder.textview.setLayoutParams(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        }
    }
```

Try adapt this idea in your project!

Comment: The problem is that I want the others itens that are before last item, continues next to it. And all the itens have different widths.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't undestand what you need, may you show us some code, or picture.

Comment: Edited question with images.

Comment: @WitaloBenicio I'm sorry, but I have no idea how to achieve this, have you tried a simple margin?